# Importance interpretation with randomForest using R

Tags: r, predictive-models, random-forest, mse

I'm working on a predictive model using randomForest. 
I have some interesting results but the important variables got me confused.

While using the `varImPlot` from the `randomForest` package, i get the result shown on the picture.
 [image]

Is it normal that the %IncMSE is greater than 100%.

Does that mean that removing `ENCEPARG20` will multiply by four (increase by ~300%) the MSE ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

***EDIT :***
I tried to change the number of tree and the `%IncMSE` change a lot. Sometimes below 100% and sometimes above. Any explaination ?

I'm using a parallel randomForest :

```
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
set.seed(42)
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(500, 2), .combine= combine, .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
randomForest(bou~.,data=train, ntree=ntree, importance=TRUE, do.trace=TRUE)}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Any idea ?